# How to use the Mean Value Theorem to prove the following statement:

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b)$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that $f '(x)$ tends to a finite limit $L$ as $x \to a^+$. Then $f(x)$ is right-differentiable at $x=a$ and $f '(a)=L$.

(epsilon-delta proof not needed).

This is a practice exam question.

I am having trouble translating this into a 'mathematical' statement. The MVT states that there exists $c$, $a\leq c\leq b$, such that:

$f'(c) = (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$

I suppose to prove that $f(x)$ is right differentiable at $x=a$, using the MVT, I need to somehow show that as $x \to a^+$, $f'(c)=f'(a)=L$ ??? Am I on the right track here? Can someone help me get started?

Comment: Apply MVT with $b=x$. As $c$ is sandwiched between $a$ and $x$, then as $x\to a+$ we also get that $c\to ?$.

Answer (score 5):

You need to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=L
$$
By mean value theorem there exist $c(x)\in(a,x)$ such that 
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(c(x)).
$$
Since for all $x\in(a,x)$ we have $c(x)\in(a,x)$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}c(x)=a$. Thus,
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}f'(c(x))=\lim\limits_{t\to a+0}f'(t)=L
$$

Comment: thanks for helping me out. Was there any particular reason, why you had c(x)? Rather than just c is a member of (a,x)? Just curious, but this helped a lot!

Comment: When I write $c(x)$ instead of $c$ I want to emphasize that choice of $c$ depends on $x$. Thus you have a function $c(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be a real number such that $h<b-a$. By assumption, $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,a+h]$ and differentiable on $(a,a+h)$. By mean-value theorem, we have
$$\tag{1}f'(c_h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
for some $c_h\in (a,a+h)$.

By definition, the right derivative of $f$ at $a$ is given by
$$\lim_{h\to 0, h>0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
which is equal to 
$$\lim_{h\to 0, h>0}f'(c_h)$$
by $(1)$. On the other hand, by assumption, 
$$\lim_{h\to 0, h>0}f'(c_h)=L.$$
The result follows from combining all these.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul. For (1), should it be h-a?