# If f is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=L$, then $f'(0) = L$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f$ is continuous and derivable, prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=L$, then $f'(0) = L$

I need help proving this, thank you.

Comment: any thoughts by your self?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "differentiable", not derivative. Could you post the question exactly as you came upon it, because right now, I'm a bit confused about what exactly needs to be proved - the problem statement for the most part looks like a definition.

Comment: The value of a function $f(x)$ at some point $x=a$ is the limiting value of $f$ as $x$ becomes arbitrarily close to $a$, so unless I didn't follow your question, the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ is by definition, $f'(0)$ where this limiting value is stated to be $f'(0)=L$,  since f(x) is also defined to be continuous and differentiable in the interval containing$x=0$.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar: you should consider the function $f$ with $f(0) = 0$, and $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $x \ne 0$. It's differentiable at $0$, be does not have the property you claim.

Comment: I suggest you add a comma in the title, so that it reads "If $f$ is continuous, and differentiable on ...", for right now, it's not clear whether "on R \ {0}" applies to "differentiable" or to both "differentiable" and "continuous". And then you should include this clarification, and the domains, etc., in the statement of the question within the question rather than just in the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Mean Value Theorem to prove the following statement:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152815/how-to-use-the-mean-value-theorem-to-prove-the-following-statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Be $f:\;(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Suppose $c\in(a,b)$ ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973344/be-f-a-b-rightarrow-mathbbr-a-continuous-function-suppose-c-ina-b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function must be defined and continuous at $0$ for this to hold.

- If $f$ is not defined at $0$, it cannot have a derivative at $0$.
- If $f$ is defined at $0$, but not continuous, it cannot have a derivative at $0$.

The result is now a simple application of l’Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}
$$
which exists by assumption

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this. It's used as a Lemma in Spivak's book, and I've never been quite certain how to prove it until now.

This is a consequence of Darboux's theorem that derivatives have the intermediate value property (i.e., if $f'(a) = A$ and $f'(b)= B$ and $A < C< B$, then there's a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ with $f'(c) = C$.)

For a discussion of that theorem, see: 
[How to prove that derivatives have the Intermediate Value Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/how-to-prove-that-derivatives-have-the-intermediate-value-property)

To prove the claim from Darboux:

First, let

$$
g(x) = f(x) - Lx.
$$
Then we have that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} g'(x) = 0
$$
and want to prove that $g'(0) = 0$. What's given is that $g$ is everywhere differentiable on $\Bbb R$ (I assume!). In particular, $g'(0)$ exists. 
$$
\newcommand{\ep} {\epsilon}
$$
Suppose that $A = g'(0) \ne 0$. Without loss of generality, suppose then that $A > 0$ (the other case is very similar).

Consider $\ep = A/3$. 
For some $\delta$, we know that $0 < |x| < \delta \implies  |f'(x)| < \ep$ by the limit assumption. In particular, picking $x_0 = \delta/2$, we have
$$
|f'(x_0)| < \frac{A}{3}.
$$

Darboux's theorem then tells us that for some $x_1$ between $0$ and $x_0$, we have 
$$
f'(x_1) = \frac{2A}{3}
$$
because $\frac{2A}{3}$ is between $A = f'(0)$ and $\pm \frac{A}{3}$, which is $f'(x_0)$. But this is a contradiction, for $|x_1| < |x_0| = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$, and the limit condition tells us that 
$$
|f'(x_1)| < \epsilon = \frac{A}{3}.
$$
But $\frac{2A}{3}$ is NOT less than $\frac{A}{3}$, because $A$ is positive.

Comment: The question says it is differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. So $g'(0)$ may not exist, right?

Comment: The question does not say that -- it says it's "derivable", which I take to mean "differentiable", and since it doesn't say where, I took that to mean "everywhere differentiable." The Spivak Lemma actually claims (I think) the thing you're suggesting: if it's differentiable away from $0$, and continuous at $0$, and the derivative limit at $0$ exists, then it's differentiable at $0$ and the derivative at $0$ is the limit of nearby derivatives. To prove that would take a bit more work.

Comment: If you see the title..

Comment: Oh, jeez. I hate it when the question and title don't match. I'm leaving this as an answer to the question asked (rather than the one asked in the title), because as egreg points out, the one in the title is false without the additional assumption of continuity. Overall, though, I prefer egreg's answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, x=0 is not necessarily on the domain of $f'(x)$.

For example:

$$f:(0,1) \to R, \\
f(x)=\sin(x), f'(x)=\cos(x), \\
\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)=1$$

but nor $f(0)$ neither $f'(0)$ exist, because they are outside of the domain, which exclude the point $x=0$.

if $f$ is differenciable, then by definition, the derivative exist on its domain, the value $f'(0)$ exist, and in particular, the limit $\lim_{x\to o}f'(x)$ exist.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=L$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=L$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f'(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. If $|x|<\delta$, take $c\in(0,x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=f'(c)$; such a $c$ exists by the mean value theorem. So,$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x-L\right|=\bigl|f'(c)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: That shows that for *some* $c$ in $(0, x)$, you have $|f'(c) - L| < \epsilon$ (in your answer, you lost the $L$ somewhere!). But it doesn't show that $|f(0) - L| < \epsilon$ -- that would require continuity of the derivative, which isn't always the case.

Comment: I have added the $L$ (twice). What I proved was that $|x|<\delta\Longrightarrow\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x-L\right|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Agreed -- my criticism on that aspect was an overstep -- apologies.